# Jump to the first position of text "<CURSOR>"

Tags: vim

I'm using a file template directory for newly created files,

`autocmd! BufNewFile * silent! 0r ~/.vim/skel/tmpl.%:e`

Now I want to add another function, that move the cursor to somewhere (defined in each ~/.vim/skel/tmpl.%), i.e the first location of text `<CURSOR>`, is that possible?

In summary, when a new file is created, use the template, and jump to `<CURSOR>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
function LoadFile()
  0r ~/.vim/skel/tmpl.%:e
  exe "normal /<CURSOR>\<Cr>"
endf

autocmd! BufNewFile * silent! call LoadFile()
```

Comment: Hi Stephane, perhaps you can take a look at this question as well  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69296/switching-to-edit-mode-in-vim-rc?noredirect=1#comment100454_69296