# Switching to edit mode in VIM rc?

Tags: vim

S[till related to the previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69293/jump-to-the-first-position-of-text-cursor), but switching mode with `exe "a"` doesn't seem to work, I still have to press the `a` button manually

Here upon opening a newly  created a file, a template is in use and the cursor will be moved to the right position, then erase the tag, and switch to the `appending (editing)` mode.

```
function LoadFile()
  0r ~/.vim/skel/tmpl.%:e
  exe "normal /<CURSOR>\<Cr>"
  exe "s#<CURSOR>##"
  exe "a"
endf

autocmd! BufNewFile * silent! call LoadFile()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to link to "the previous question" so it is clear what you are refrring to (if it is relevant to this question)...

Comment: @jasonwryan added

Comment: `:help startinsert`

Comment: Add `d%` ot `df>` after the `\<Cr>` there. You don't need exe for the other ones mine was just to expand `\<Cr>`. I'm not sure it's even necessary there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, that would be `:normal! a` instead of `:exe "a"`; this is a normal-mode command.

Second, for implementation reasons, that does not work; you have to use the special `:startinsert!` command.